# Access different page for different sub-domains having same domain?

Tags: php, subdomain, cpanel

I have a panel whose url is E.g abc(subdomain).domain.com, For "abc" I have different page to access and for another subdomain like "xyz(subdomain)" I have to access different page. I have added condition in index.php which is at location public_html/

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "abc.example.com"){
    require("test.php");
}else{
    require("test_folder/test-2.php");
}
```

It works fine when $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "abc.example.com" but on giving 2nd subdomain it shows HTTP ERROR 500 . I am new in it and don't have enough knowledge that how should I access different page for subdomains which is having same domain name. How it should be possible to open different page on the basis of their subdomain. Any help will be appreciated. If anyone needs more info, let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: I would turn on PHP error reporting, if it's only 500ing on the second link, it may be the file path is incorrect or the file has an error in it.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.